# Function as function parameter

Tags: typescript

In Typescript, I need to pass a function to another function as a parameter with default; in the caller, I wrote:

```
const fixCountryGroup=(
            countryGroups: WithId<country_groups.CountryGroup<"ISO3166A3">>[]
        ): WithId<country_groups.CountryGroup<"ISO3166A3">>[] {
            const excludedCountries: string[] = ["TOTAL", "EU28_FOR", "NEU28_FOR"];
            return countryGroups.filter((record) => {
                return !excludedCountries.includes(record.ISO3166A3);
            });
        }
```

and the function call is:

```
 c += this.buildAggregation(
            self.tempRecordsSingleOrigin,
            self.dstCollection,
            false,
            {
                age: "$extras.age",
                sex: "$extras.sex",
                c_citizen: "$extras.c_citizen"
            },
            "$time_dim",
            "$time_dim_value",
            idExtra,
            fixCountryGroup
        );
```

Now, in the called function, I have:

```
   protected buildAggregation(
        collection: Collection<DDHRecordSingleOrigin>,
        aggCollection: Collection<DDHRecord>,
        reverse: boolean = false,
        additionalGroupingIdFields: { [k: string]: string } = {},
        timeDimField: string = "$time_dim",
        timeDimValueField = "$time_dim_value",
        extrasProvider: (
            record: DDHAggregationRecord
        ) => { [key: string]: any } = (_d) => {
            return {};
        },
        fixCountryGroup: (
            countryGroups: WithId<country_groups.CountryGroup<"ISO3166A3">>[]
        ) => { countryGroups: WithId<country_groups.CountryGroup<"ISO3166A3">>[] | undefined} = (x){return undefined}
```

The error on fixCountryGroup parameter is:

```
(parameter) fixCountryGroup: (countryGroups: WithId<country_groups.CountryGroup<"ISO3166A3">>[]) => {
    countryGroups: WithId<country_groups.CountryGroup<"ISO3166A3">>[] | undefined;
}
Type '(x: WithId<CountryGroup<"ISO3166A3">>[]) => undefined' is not assignable to type '(countryGroups: WithId<CountryGroup<"ISO3166A3">>[]) => { countryGroups: WithId<CountryGroup<"ISO3166A3">>[] | undefined; }'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ countryGroups: WithId<CountryGroup<"ISO3166A3">>[] | undefined; }'.ts(2322)
```

How do I have to write the fixCountryGroup parameter in the called function?!?

Answer (score 0):

not sure which you want but do this (fix return type to allow undefined):

```
fixCountryGroup: (
    countryGroups: WithId<country_groups.CountryGroup<"ISO3166A3">>[]
) => { countryGroups: WithId<country_groups.CountryGroup<"ISO3166A3">>[] } | undefined = (x) => undefined
```

or this (fix default fn to return allowed interface):

```
fixCountryGroup: (
    countryGroups: WithId<country_groups.CountryGroup<"ISO3166A3">>[]
) => { countryGroups: WithId<country_groups.CountryGroup<"ISO3166A3">>[] | undefined } = (x) => ({countryGroups: undefined })
```

Comment: my problem is: pass a function parameter to another function OR call the function without this function parameter and add a default to the called function; with simple variable I use the = symbol in the parameter list, but how to do it with a function? I want to call the function with OR without the fixCountryGroup parameter.